# Different result on count(*) when do left join

Tags: mysql

I have 2 different tables one is product and other count number of quantity in second table.
Count(*) gives different result when use left join condition and group by

LEFT JOIN ON and GROUP BY is different below is the query.

```
SELECT LEFT( substring_index(dp_ventes_par_segments.ref_article,'/',-1),LOCATE('-', substring_index(dp_ventes_par_segments.ref_article,'/',-1)) - 1)  as r,

COUNT(*) 
FROM `dp_ventes_par_segments`  

LEFT JOIN dp_ventes_qty 
ON dp_ventes_par_segments.ref_article=dp_ventes_qty.dp_ventes_id 

GROUP BY 
LEFT( substring_index(dp_ventes_par_segments.ref_article,'/',-1),LOCATE('-', substring_index(dp_ventes_par_segments.ref_article,'/',-1)) - 1)
```

dp_ventes_par_segments

| ref_article |
| --- |
| P-00493/ANY-C2-O |
| P-00492/ANY-C4-O |

dp_ventes_qty

| dp_ventes_id | date |
| --- | --- |
| P-00493/ANY-C2-O | 2023-10-01 |
| P-00493/ANY-C2-O | 2023-10-01 |
| P-00493/ANY-C2-O | 2023-10-01 |
| P-00493/ANY-C4-O | 2023-10-01 |

table dp_ventes_par_segments.ref_article and dp_ventes_qty.dp_ventes_id data contents like below

```
P-00493/ANY-C2-O
P-00492/ANY-C4-O
```

And Result Is wants below:

```
ANY - 2
```

Count ANY is 2

Comment: When you use `LEFT JOIN` you get rows in the first table that have no match in the second table. These will be counted. Use `INNER JOIN` to keep them out.

Comment: BTW, you can use `GROUP BY r` instead of repeating the expression.

Comment: If the second table has a `quantity` column, maybe you just want to select that instead of using `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.x you can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` instead of that complicated combination of functions.

Comment: Please add sample data as text for both tables in tabular form. as is I can't figure put where the elements P-00493/ANY-C2-O live.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
  LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dp_ventes_par_segments.ref_article, '/', -1),
       LOCATE('-', SUBSTRING_INDEX(dp_ventes_par_segments.ref_article, '/', -1)) - 1) AS r,
  COUNT(*) AS count_result
FROM
  dp_ventes_par_segments
LEFT JOIN
  dp_ventes_qty ON dp_ventes_par_segments.ref_article = dp_ventes_qty.dp_ventes_id
GROUP BY
  r;
```

You can also use `INNER JOIN` if you only want to include rows with matching values in both tables.

Comment: Not working same result on INNER and LEFT JOIN